# NPGSQL DataReader fails in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, npgsql

I am using NpgsqlDataReader to read from the database. Datareader's 'HasRows=true' yet the result collection is empty.

Error - '"Enumeration yielded no results". 
npgsql version - 4.0.3 , .net framework  - 4.5 , VS version - 2015.

I am able to fire ExecuteScalar to the same database and retrieve data without any issue.

The same code with NpgsqlDataReader works fine in VS 2012.

Here is my code.

```
        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string sql3 = @"testfunction";             
            NpgsqlCommand pgcom = new NpgsqlCommand(sql3, conn);
            pgcom.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            NpgsqlParameter para = new NpgsqlParameter();
            para.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            para.ParameterName = @"param1";
            para.SourceColumn = @"param1column";
            para.Value = 101010;
            pgcom.Parameters.Add(para);               

            NpgsqlDataReader pgreader = pgcom.ExecuteReader();
            if (pgreader.HasRows)
            {
                while (pgreader.Read())
                {
                    string cust_id = pgreader.GetString(1);
                    ...
                }
            }
```

am I doing something wrong here please or is is my .Net version . Tried compiling the project in .Net 4.0 but no luck..

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqZIw.png)

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE. It doesn't do anything except act as a development tool. It's always more useful to include a tag for the actual language you're using, in this case C#. I've edited to add it for you, but please keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: Sure. thanks  Ken White.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: The error occurs at accessing the values after the call pgreader.Read(), as the row values are not populated. Updated the original with the error screenshot.

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2216